# Encoding the large string column

Tags: python

I have a large dataset (40000 rows) with a column (name of artists) in different languages. how to encode the column name?

```
# Create a OneHotEncoder instance
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

# Fit and transform the OneHotEncoder using the categorical variable list
artists_encode_df = pd.DataFrame(enc.fit_transform(artists_df[artists_cat]))

# Add the encoded variable names to the dataframe
artists_encode_df.columns = enc.get_feature_names(artists_cat)
artists_encode_df.head()
```

I used the above piece of code but after merging to the original dataframe it gave me the memoryerror.